# Ngrok security concerns

Tags: security, flask, shopify, webhooks, ngrok

It is my first question and my first project, I hope to make it clear and not bother.
I am developing a basic flask server with python to receive webhooks from shopify, I opened a local port through ngrok, however I noticed that it was a huge mistake in case someone guessed the ip. Therefore, I read that the command -> **`ngrok http 3000 --verify-webhook shopify --verify-webhook-secret {your signing secret}`** may add security.

Does this command open the port exclusively for the webhooks received from the Shopify URL? Or there are still vulnerabilities?

Thank you for the help,have a great day!

I expect to ensure that the ngrok tunnel used on my server has no vulnerabilities

Comment: Guessing the IP alone won't help; ngrok is hostname based.

Answer (score 0):

When you open an NGROK tunnel to your computer, you can receive webhooks at an endpoint you specify when you created the webhook. Note that regardless of using a tunnel or a real DNS URL, you receive data to that endpoint. It is by inspecting the header for authentication tokens that you decide if the data is a friend or foe.

This is not a mistake. If someone guesses your service endpoint and hits it with requests, your inner security mechanism would examine the header, and decide if the request was valid or not.